IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX still causing ORA-00001 error
I have the following table:
CREATE TABLE "43CY".AMSTBL_B2BTST
(
    TSMPF    VARCHAR(5), 
    TSCALLRN VARCHAR(3), 
    TSCALLR2 VARCHAR(15), 

    CONSTRAINT AMSCNS_B2BTST 
        PRIMARY KEY (TSMPF, TSCALLRN, TSCALLR2)
);

Which seemingly creates the table successfully:

... along with the constraint:

and the index:

Still, if I run the following script, it fails, throwing an ORA-00001 error (unique constraint):


As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

It is not good programming practice to use hints that change the behavior/result. That Oracle even has lately offered a few such hints is mind-boggling, but it doesn't make it a good practice. You are far better off explicitly trapping a PK violation and handling it as an exception, or querying it first before inserting, than relying on a hint to break or not break your code. Hints should be used only for performance reasons. They are not guaranteed to always work.

Remove the schema name from the hint and the code will run without raising an exception:
BEGIN
  INSERT /*+ IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX (AMSTBL_B2BTST, AMSCNS_B2BTST) */
  INTO "43CY".AMSTBL_B2BTST
    (TSMPF, TSCALLRN, TSCALLR2)
  VALUES
    ('431', 'RPR', 'A');
END;
/

The syntax diagram from the manual shows that the schema name should not be used in these hints:


The “Specifying Global Hints” section in the same doc says that explicitly (and also mentions using aliases.
